# How to view online url pdf from my flutter windows app?

Tags: flutter, url, pdf-viewer

How to **view online pdf file** from my **flutter windows** application?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `webview_flutter` plugin for this:

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter